Icon not displaying correctly on KDE Plasma panel
I had a version of Tracktion Waveform running that I had to install from a .deb file. The icon displayed correctly in the panel when I opened the program. Then I installed a more recent version of the same program, but the icon does not display correctly. It's like it is missing. The program runs fine, the icon is just missing. I wonder if there might be a fix for this.


You've provided few specifics; we don't know what release of Ubuntu/Kubuntu you're using, nor what actual package you did install (was it a deb, flatpak, appimage, from source etc) as you only gave some specifics for a version that you're no longer using. You could use the icon from the prior version if you wanted; but you'll need to be specific as to what you installed & whether or not the prior is still available.  Some packages don't contain anything but binary code; others contain icons, pixmaps & more... but you've not given more than app name.

It is Ubuntu studio 24.04. The program is tracktion waveform. I installed it from a .deb file. The icon worked. I installed a later version of waveform (also a .deb file) and when I open the later version there is just an 'X' where the icon should be. When I open the earlier version the icon displays correctly. I woud try to delete the earlier version but it doesn't just uninstall nicely as it didn't come from 'Discover'. Plus the older version seems to use the same folders. I would be happy to use the icon from the earlier version. I hope this is sufficient info.
